# SendMessage API in 64 bit

Tags: c++, c, winapi

According to MSDN

> The return value specifies the result
>   of the message processing; it depends
>   on the message sent.

I know it is defined as

```
typedef LONG_PTR LRESULT;
```

Meaning it will be 8 bytes on 64bit machine but it doesn't!

Does anyone know if it is safe to assume that only the lower 4 bytes are used and store it as an `INT` (for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not safe, because the return value is defined by the message being sent and the handler.

If you control the handler and the message then it'd be possible, it's not safe in the general case.

James

Answer (score 1):

No it is not safe in general. Do not assume the downcast. Also, useful is to compile your code with /RTCc which ensures inadvertent casts are asserted at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not safe. If the message return is indeed a pointer, it is very well possible for the pointer to have its 33rd bit set - especially on machines with >4GB memory.

Comment: This may also happen with less than 4GB, due to the memory virtualization.